# Replace values in a pandas series via dictionary efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, dictionary

How to replace values in a Pandas series `s` via a dictionary `d` has been asked and re-asked many times.

The recommended method ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40855794/9209546), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40528697/9209546), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45355744/9209546), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20250996/9209546)) is to either use `s.replace(d)` or, occasionally, use `s.map(d)` if all your series values are found in the dictionary keys.

However, performance using `s.replace` is often unreasonably slow, often 5-10x slower than a simple list comprehension.

The alternative, `s.map(d)` has good performance, but is only recommended when all keys are found in the dictionary.

Why is `s.replace` so slow and how can performance be improved?

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000000)})
lst = df['A'].values.tolist()

##### TEST 1 #####

d = {i: i+1 for i in range(1000)}

%timeit df['A'].replace(d)                          # 1.98s
%timeit [d[i] for i in lst]                         # 134ms

##### TEST 2 #####

d = {i: i+1 for i in range(10)}

%timeit df['A'].replace(d)                          # 20.1ms
%timeit [d.get(i, i) for i in lst]                  # 243ms
```

**Note:** This question is not marked as a duplicate because it is looking for specific advice on *when to use* different methods given different datasets. This is explicit in the answer and is an aspect not usually addressed in other questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)

Comment: @JohnE, You're right, I only found your answer ~1w later. Hopefully, the explanation I gave helps people notice when (if & when) the behaviour changes via the source code. Feel free to mark this as a dup :).

Comment: No worries, it's fine, too much stuff here gets marked as dupes IMO  ;-)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

One trivial solution is to choose a method dependent on an estimate of how completely values are covered by dictionary keys.

**General case**

- Use `df['A'].map(d)` if all values mapped; or
- Use `df['A'].map(d).fillna(df['A']).astype(int)` if >5% values mapped.

**Few, e.g. < 5%, values in d**

- Use `df['A'].replace(d)`

The "crossover point" of ~5% is specific to Benchmarking below.

Interestingly, a simple list comprehension generally underperforms `map` in either scenario.

**Benchmarking**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000000)})
lst = df['A'].values.tolist()

##### TEST 1 - Full Map #####

d = {i: i+1 for i in range(1000)}

%timeit df['A'].replace(d)                          # 1.98s
%timeit df['A'].map(d)                              # 84.3ms
%timeit [d[i] for i in lst]                         # 134ms

##### TEST 2 - Partial Map #####

d = {i: i+1 for i in range(10)}

%timeit df['A'].replace(d)                          # 20.1ms
%timeit df['A'].map(d).fillna(df['A']).astype(int)  # 111ms
%timeit [d.get(i, i) for i in lst]                  # 243ms
```

**Explanation**

The reason why `s.replace` is so slow is that it does much more than simply map a dictionary. It deals with some edge cases and arguably rare situations, which typically merit more care in any case.

This is an excerpt from `replace()` in [`pandas\generic.py`](http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L4373-L4621).

```
items = list(compat.iteritems(to_replace))
keys, values = zip(*items)
are_mappings = [is_dict_like(v) for v in values]

if any(are_mappings):
    # handling of nested dictionaries
else:
    to_replace, value = keys, values

return self.replace(to_replace, value, inplace=inplace,
                    limit=limit, regex=regex)
```

There appear to be many steps involved:

- Converting dictionary to a list.
- Iterating through list and checking for nested dictionaries.
- Feeding an iterator of keys and values into a replace function.

This can be compared to much leaner code from `map()` in [`pandas\series.py`](http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/series.py#L2229-L2357):

```
if isinstance(arg, (dict, Series)):
    if isinstance(arg, dict):
        arg = self._constructor(arg, index=arg.keys())

    indexer = arg.index.get_indexer(values)
    new_values = algos.take_1d(arg._values, indexer)
```