# Change every value in a dataframe column to the value returned by a function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a column containing a string value. I need to replace each value in that column with the results of a function.  I'd like to do this without iterating over thousands of rows. The function takes a term and returns the approved new value of that term.

**Example**: `getPreferredTerm('STAINED')` would return 'DISCOLORED' so values of 'STAINED' in the P_TERM column would all be replaced by 'DISCOLORED'.

I'm struggling with using `numpy` to accomplish this.

```
df['P_TERM'] = getPreferredTerm(df['P_TERM'])
```

the getPreferredTerm function is as follows:

```
def getPreferredTerm(stresc): 
    # NOTE" obsData is a dataframe containing legacy terms in a 
    # column called 'STRESC' and preferred terms in a column 
    # named 'PTERM' so this function takes a legacy term as input 
    # and returns a preferred term 
    try:    
        df = obsData.loc[(obsData['STRESC'] == stresc)].iloc[0]['P_TERM'] 
        pterm = df 
    except Exception as e:  
        pterm = 'UNMAPPED' 
    return pterm
```

is it possible to vectorize this function if I pass it a series instead of a single value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) to apply a function to each element in a series:

```
df['P_TERM'] = df['P_TERM'].apply(getPreferredTerm)
```

Note that such a calculation will not be vectorised, nor is it in-place. Pandas will perform a loop to apply your function to each value in the series. The resulting series is then assigned back to the dataframe.

---

If you want to use a dictionary to map your values, you can use `pd.Series.map`. This operation is optimized by Pandas.

```
d = {'STAINED': 'DISCOLORED'}
df['P_TERM'] = df['P_TERM'].map(d).fillna(df['P_TERM'])
```

An alternative is to use `pd.Series.replace`, but see this [note on performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259580/replace-values-in-a-pandas-series-via-dictionary-efficiently).

---

Vectorised method for your updated requirements:

```
s = obsData.drop_duplicates(subset=['STRESC']).set_index('STRESC')['P_TERM']
df['P_TERM'] = df['P_TERM'].map(s).fillna('UNMAPPED')
```

Comment: Will this be faster than iterating through each row?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This will be no faster than iterating each row. If you want a vectorised method, you need to show us the code for `getPreferredTerm`, which may or may not be vectorisable.

Comment: def getObsPTerm (stresc):
        # NOTE" obsData is a dataframe containing legacy terms in a 
        # column called 'STRESC' and preferred terms in a column 
        # named 'PTERM'  so this function takes a legacy term as input 
        # and returns a preferred term
 try: 
  df = obsData.loc[(obsData['STRESC'] == stresc)].iloc[0]['P_TERM']
  pterm = df
 except Exception as e:  
  pterm =  'UNMAPPED'
 return pterm

Comment: @summersmd, Sorry I cannot read code in your comment. Please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49901415/edit)** your question if you need to provide more data / code.

Comment: @summersmd, see update. You haven't provided data with expected output, so I cannot test to see if this is what you want.

Comment: @jp...  Thanks for the assist.  Your suggestion works great (s = obsData.drop_duplicates(subset=['STRESC']).set_index('STRESC')['P_TERM']
df['P_TERM'] = df['P_TERM'].map(s).fillna('UNMAPPED'))

I have a new wrinkle.  What if my def getPreferredTerm(stresc) function actually required 2 inputs (stresc, category)?

If the preferred term was looked up using stresc and a category, example:

STRESC    CATEGORY  P_TERM
Stained       Hair                Discolored