# Pandas add a column based on a composite condition on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is

```
| A  | B |
| -- | -- |
| 1  | good |
| 2  | bad  |
| 3  | bad  |
| 4  | mid  |
```

and I want to add another column that transforms the B column into numbers, so that if B is "good" you get a 1, if B is "bad" you get a 0 and if B is "mid" you get another number, say 2.

What is the most effective way to do this, given that the dataframe is quite large? I could use a lambda function and `.apply`, this is one way, not particularly efficient. Using filtering you could do things like

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['B']=='good', 1, 0)
```

which would allow me to use a binary condition and is very fast. But to make it do both conditions I'd have to use two of those statements. I wonder if there is a way to use an efficient filtering with a double condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary. For example define:

```
d = {'good': 1, 'bad': 0, 'mid': 2}
```

Then use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), which accepts a dictionary as an input:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].map(d)
```

You can also use [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html), but this method often yields poor performance.

Related: [Replace values in a pandas series via dictionary efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259580/replace-values-in-a-pandas-series-via-dictionary-efficiently)