# Search and replace matching values across data frames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, replace

I have the following Pandas Dataframes:

df1:

```
C   D   E   F   G
111 222 333 444 555
666 777
```

df2:

```
A    B 
111  3
222  4
333  3
444  3
555  4
100  3
666  4
200  3
777  3
```

I need to look up in df2 to find matching value from df1.A Then replace that value in df1 with the paired valued in df2.B

So the required output would be:

```
C   D   E   F   G
3   4   3   3   4
4   3
```

I tried a left merge and thought to try and reshape the values across but thought there must be a simpler / cleaner direct search and replace method. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
temp=df2.set_index('A')['B']
print df1.replace(temp)
```

Output:

```
   C  D    E    F    G
0  3  4  3.0  3.0  4.0
1  4  3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I'm using python 2.x :)

Comment: A couple of notes: (1) `pd.DataFrame.replace` accepts a series, so no `dict` conversion required, (2) `map` [usually outperforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259580/replace-values-in-a-pandas-series-via-dictionary-efficiently) `replace`.

Comment: @jpp - thanks for your help updated to the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

First create a series mapping:

```
s = df2.set_index('A')['B']
```

Then apply this to each value:

```
df1 = df1.applymap(s.get)
```