# Replace value in a specific with corresponding value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace, replacewith

I have a dataframe called `REF` with the following structure:

```
old_id  new_id
     3       6
     4       7
     5       8
```

I want to replace all the values that can be found equal to any of the `old_id` values in another dataframe `NEW` that is:

```
old_id  column_1  column_2
     3         a         e
     4         b         f
     9         c         g
     9         d         h
```

Therefore the new output dataset `NEW` will be:

```
old_id  column_1  column_2
     6         a         e
     7         b         f
     9         c         g
     9         d         h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df1.set_index('old_id')['new_id']

df2['old_id'] = df2['old_id'].map(s).fillna(df2['old_id'])
```

Or [slowier solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49259580/2901002) with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df2['old_id'] = df2['old_id'].replace(s)
```