# How to replace a Series of booleans with a Series of strings?

Tags: python, pandas

A solution would be to use **replace()** twice:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([True, False, False])

s = s.replace(False, "A")
s = s.replace(True, 'B')
```

Then,

```
Out[1]: 
0    B
1    A
2    A
```

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: One pass: `s.apply(lambda v: {False: "A", True: "B"}[v])`

Comment: There are [some reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259581/9209546) why `replace` is inefficient here.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = np.where(s, 'B', 'A')
```

This is much faster than `map` and `apply`, if you are feeding a Boolean series:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice([True, False], 1000000))

%%timeit
np.where(s, 'A','B')
```

4.43 ms ± 94.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
mapper={True:'B',False:'A'}

%%timeit
s.map(mapper)
```

44.1 ms ± 178 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%%timeit
s.apply(lambda x: 'B' if x else 'A')
```

126 ms ± 4.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: I was going to suggest this. I can't test atm but I suspect it's faster than `map`?

Comment: @roganjosh, Not sure about performance. Probably not a bottleneck, but worth testing :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `map`

```
mapper={True:'B',False:'A'}
s = s.map(mapper)
s
Out[598]: 
0    B
1    A
2    A
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([True, False, False])
>>> s = s.apply(lambda x: 'B' if x else 'A')
>>> s
0    B
1    A
2    A
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command using .map() function:

```
s = pd.Series([True, False, False])
s = s.map({True: 'A', False: 'B'})
print(s)
```

or you can also try the another way using lambda function under .map() function:

```
s = pd.Series([True, False, False])
s = s.map(lambda x: "A" if x else "B")        
print(s)
```