# Converting 'no' and 'yes' into 0 and 1 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to convert data of 'edjefe' column which contains int as well as 'yes' and 'no' values. My problem is I just want to map 'yes' and 'no' to  1 and 0 and keep the int values as it is
So I wrote this code

```
def foo(x):
    if x == 'no':
        return 0
    elif x == 'yes':
        return 1
    else:
        return x
```

and `df1.edjefe.map(lambda x : foo(x))`

But I am getting an error as,

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: Full traceback where?

Comment: maybe `apply` the function instead of `map`. But hard to assess the error without a working example

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` (or `numpy`) - kindly do not spam the tags (removed)

Comment: same error with the `apply`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can also just use `replace`:

`df.edjefe.replace(to_replace=['no', 'yes'], value=[0, 1])`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'`

Comment: String replace requires a string as an input and an output.  Replace yes and no with `value=['0', '1']`, then cast the result with `int()`.

Comment: Note also that `replace` has a flag `inplace=True` for replacing the values in the dataframe in-place, rather than returning the modified values.

Answer (score 8):

Just use dict-like `to_replace`:

```
df['edjefe'].replace({'no': 0, 'yes': 1})
```

Comment: what about all the columns?

Comment: @mLstudent33, just use `replace` on the full DataFrame, not specific column: `df.replace({'no': 0, 'yes': 1})`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with a dictionary mapping followed by [`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
d = {'no': 0, 'yes': 1}
df1['edjefe'] = df1['edjefe'].map(d).fillna(df1['edjefe'])
```

You will likely find this more efficient than `pd.Series.replace`.

See [Replace values in a pandas series via dictionary efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259580/replace-values-in-a-pandas-series-via-dictionary-efficiently) for more details.

If you have mutable objects in your series, this will fail, since dictionary keys must be hashable. You can convert to strings in this case:

```
df1['edjefe'] = df1['edjefe'].astype(str).map(d).fillna(df1['edjefe'])
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` error

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar, Can you provide a [mcve]? I cannot replicate your error.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar, Also, see update. Seems you might have `list` or other mutable types in your series.

Comment: Got it the 0 and 1 are of type str. Tnx

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar, Nope that's incorrect. We're converting series elements to `str` as an intermediary step to ensure elements are hashable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
df1['edjefe'] = (df1['edjefe']=="yes")*1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.Categorical as well.

`df1["edjefe"] = pd.Categorical(df1["edjefe"]).codes`

Visit [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) for more information.