# Find and replace loop in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which has a lot of characters that need changing.

I can do this line by line but I couldn't figure out how to loop through these characters to replace with a new character.

This is my code so far:

```
df_media_input['MediaChannel']=df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, "Direct Mail","DM"))
df_media_input['MediaChannel']=df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, "DR TV","DRTV"))
df_media_input['MediaChannel']=df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, "Affilliates","Affiliates"))
df_media_input['MediaChannel']=df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, "DRTV","TV"))
df_media_input['MediaChannel']=df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, "All Time TV","TV"))
df_media_input['MediaChannel']=df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, "Peak TV","TV"))
df_media_input['MediaChannel']=df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, "Regional Press","Press"))
df_media_input['MediaChannel']=df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, "National Press","Press"))
```

but I feel something like this should be possible:

```
dic= {Direct Mail:DM}


for i and j in dic:

df_media_input['MediaChannel']=df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, i,j))
```

where Direct Mail is i
and DM is j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pandas DataFrame `replace` methods accepts a dictionary where the keys correspond to existing strings and the values correspond to the string to replace each with.

So in your example:

```
replacements = {
    "Direct Mail": "DM",
    "DR TV": "DRTV",
    # and so on...
}

df_media_input['MediaChannel'].replace(replacements, inplace=True)
```

Assuming that the values in the 'MediaChannel' column are just the strings to replace and do not *contain* those strings. For example, `"Direct Mail"` will be changed to `"DM"`, however `"I like Direct Mail"` will not be changed to `"I like DM"`. To handle this case with substrings, you'll need to set the `regex` keyword argument of `replace` to `True`.

Comment: @fred.schwartz - If performance is  important, rather use [map + fillna](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49259580/2901002)

Answer (score 2):

First create dictionary for replacing:

```
d = {"Direct Mail":"DM", 
     "DR TV":"DRTV",
     ...}
```

If want replace substrings use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `regex=True`:

```
df_media_input['MediaChannel'] = df_media_input['MediaChannel'].replace(d, regex=True)
```

If want replace values faster way use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df_media_input['MediaChannel'] = df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(d)
                                     .fillna(df_media_input['MediaChannel'])
```

Check difference in sample:

```
df_media_input = pd.DataFrame({'MediaChannel':['Direct Mail','DR TV new','val']})
print (df_media_input)
  MediaChannel
0  Direct Mail
1    DR TV new
2          val

d = {"Direct Mail":"DM", "DR TV":"DRTV"}


df_media_input['MediaChannel1'] = df_media_input['MediaChannel'].replace(d, regex=True)

df_media_input['MediaChannel2'] = (df_media_input['MediaChannel'].map(d)
                                     .fillna(df_media_input['MediaChannel']))
print (df_media_input)
  MediaChannel MediaChannel1 MediaChannel2
0  Direct Mail            DM            DM
1    DR TV new      DRTV new     DR TV new
2          val           val           val
```

Comment: df_media_input['MediaChannel'] = df_media_input['MediaChannel'].replace(d, regex=True)

Comment: should the above change from Fre&d to Fred?

Comment: I'm getting this; error: nothing to repeat at position 0

Comment: what is `d` ? like `d = {"Fre&d":"Fred"}` ? Then `regex=True` not working

Comment: d being a dictionary with find values : replace values

Comment: basically I want to find a all values in a dictionary and replace these values with replacements. for all rows in a column

Comment: @fred.schwartz - hmmm, so another solution not working? Because is necessary repalce by substring?

Comment: yeah the values might be with in a string of text, rather that the full value

Comment: I can do it like this df['name'] = df['name'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, "&",""))

Comment: but would quite like to do that for multiple values and not repeat that line of code

Comment: @fred.schwartz - Ya, I think best is create new question about it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to iterate, you could do something like this.

```
for i in range(len(df)):

    d = {"Direct Mail":"DM",
         "DR TV":"DRTV",
         "DRTV":"TV",
         "All Time TV":"TV",
         "Peak TV":"TV",
         "Regional Press":"Press",
         "National Press":"Press"
     }
    for x,y in d.items(): 
        df['MediaChannel'].values[i] = df['MediaChannel'].values[i].replace(x, y)
```