# Filling a pandas column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I would like to fill each row of a column of my dataframe based on the entries in another column, in particular I want to fill each row with the corresponding name of the corresponding ticker for that stock, like so

```
dict1 = [{'ticker': 'AAPL','Name': 'Apple Inc.'},
 {'ticker': 'MSFT','Name': 'Microsoft Corporation'}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

This function provides the name for a given ticker:

So I can pull the name for for say MSFT:

```
dict1 = [{'ticker': 'AAPL','Name': 'Apple Inc.'},
 {'ticker': 'MSFT','Name': get_nasdaq_symbols().loc['MSFT'].loc['Security Name'][:-15]}]
```

I am struggling to find a way to automate this with a for loop or apply. Can anyone suggest an approach?

Note, the function used to pull the name comes from here:

```
 from pandas_datareader.nasdaq_trader import get_nasdaq_symbols
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create a series mapping:

```
ticker_name_map = get_nasdaq_symbols()['Security Name'].str[:-15]
```

Then use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)<sup>1</sup>:

```
df1['Name'] = df1['ticker'].map(ticker_name_map)
```

If you wish unmapped values to remain unchanged, then use a subsequent `fillna`:

```
df1['Name'] = df1['ticker'].map(ticker_name_map).fillna(df1['Name'])
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) is also possible, but [inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259580/replace-values-in-a-pandas-series-via-dictionary-efficiently).