# Adding a df column based on other column with multiple values map to the same new column value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'green', 'blue']})
```

and I want a new column that gives the category, like this:

```
dfoutput = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'green', 'blue'],
                         'col2' : ['animal', 'animal', 'animal', 'color', 'color']})
```

I know I could do it inefficiently using `.loc`:

```
df1.loc[df1['col1'] == 'cat','col2'] = 'animal'
df1.loc[df1['col1'] == 'dog','col2'] = 'animal'
```

How do I combine `cat` and `dog` to both be `animal`? This doesn't work:

```
df1.loc[df1['col1'] == 'cat' | df1['col1'] == 'dog','col2'] = 'animal'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Build your `dict` then do `map`

```
d={'dog':'ani','cat':'ani','green':'color','blue':'color'}
df1['col2']=df1.col1.map(d)
df1
    col1   col2
0    cat    ani
1    cat    ani
2    dog    ani
3  green  color
4   blue  color
```

Answer (score 3):

Since multiple items may belong to a single category I suggest you start with a dictionary mapping category to items:

```
cat_item = {'animal': ['cat', 'dog'], 'color': ['green', 'blue']}
```

You'll probably find this easier to maintain. *Then* reverse your dictionary using a dictionary comprehension, followed by [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
item_cat = {w: k for k, v in cat_item.items() for w in v}

df1['col2'] = df1['col1'].map(item_cat)

print(df1)

    col1    col2
0    cat  animal
1    cat  animal
2    dog  animal
3  green   color
4   blue   color
```

You can also use [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html), but this will be generally [less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259581/9209546).

Answer (score 0):

you could also try using np.select like this:

```
options = [(df1.col1.str.contains('cat|dog')), 
           (df1.col1.str.contains('green|blue'))]

settings = ['animal', 'color']

df1['setting'] = np.select(options,settings)
```

I've found this works quite fast even with very big dataframes