# Mapping values in place (for example with Gender) from string to int in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I have a Dataframe called `df_base` that looks like this. As you can see, there's a column called `Sex` that's `male` or `female`. I want to map these values to 0 and 1, respectively.

```
+---+-------------+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------+--------+-----+-------+-------+------------------+---------+-------+----------+
|   | PassengerId | Survived | Pclass |                       Name                        |  Sex   | Age | SibSp | Parch |      Ticket      |  Fare   | Cabin | Embarked |
+---+-------------+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------+--------+-----+-------+-------+------------------+---------+-------+----------+
| 0 |           1 |        0 |      3 | Braund, Mr. Owen Harris                           | male   |  22 |     1 |     0 | A/5 21171        |    7.25 | NaN   | S        |
| 1 |           2 |        1 |      1 | Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th... | female |  38 |     1 |     0 | PC 17599         | 71.2833 | C85   | C        |
| 2 |           3 |        1 |      3 | Heikkinen, Miss. Laina                            | female |  26 |     0 |     0 | STON/O2. 3101282 |   7.925 | NaN   | S        |
| 3 |           4 |        1 |      1 | Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)      | female |  35 |     1 |     0 | 113803           |    53.1 | C123  | S        |
| 4 |           5 |        0 |      3 | Allen, Mr. William Henry                          | male   |  35 |     0 |     0 | 373450           |    8.05 | NaN   | S        |
+---+-------------+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------+--------+-----+-------+-------+------------------+---------+-------+----------+
```

There's a few methods that I've seen dotted about on StackOverflow but I'm wondering what the most efficient is to perform the following mapping:

```
+---------+---------+
| Old Sex | New Sex |
+---------+---------+
| male    |       0 |
| female  |       1 |
| female  |       1 |
| female  |       1 |
| male    |       0 |
+---------+---------+
```

I'm using this:

`df_base['Sex'].replace(['male','female'],[0,1],inplace=True)`

... but I can't help but feel as though this is a little shoddy. Is there a better way of doing this? There's also using `.loc` but that loops around the rows of the Dataframe, so is less efficient, right?

Comment: Why do I not see people suggesting duplicates when the question is _actually_ a duplicate?

Comment: @coldspeed, I never got to know about this thread So, couldn't broadcast it as dups.

Comment: @pygo I have nothing against people suggesting dupes, but I dislike double standards. I see it everywhere, and more for some users than others.

Comment: @coldspeed - Yes, standard solution is replace/map, but if OP need performnce there are also another solutions, so no closed by dupe from me.

Comment: @jezrael Every question can be left open with that reasoning. I am sure you have used the same reasoning to answer similar questions before, so find one of those and mark as dupe. Or add an answer to the dupe target. You will get much more rep that way, than answering questions like this over and over again.

Comment: @coldspeed - yes, but here are only 2 values in `Sex` column, so it is only special case, so not possible add answer to dupe - it is good general solution for replace for many values... Because only 2 replacement values is possible faster solution.

Answer (score 7):

I think here is better/faster use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary if only `male` and `female` exist in column `Sex`:

```
df_base['Sex'] = df_base['Sex'].map(dict(zip(['male','female'],[0,1]))
```

What is same like:

```
df_base['Sex'] = df_base['Sex'].map({'male': 0,'female': 1})
```

Solution if exist only `female` and `male` values is cast boolean mask to integers `True/False` to `1,0`:

```
df_base['Sex'] = (df_base['Sex'] == 'female').astype(int)
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

import perfplot    

def ma(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['Sex_new'] = df['Sex'].map({'male': 0,'female': 1})
    return df

def rep1(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].replace(['male','female'],[0,1])
    return df

def nwhere(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['Sex_new'] = np.where(df['Sex'] == 'male', 0, 1)
    return df

def mask1(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['Sex_new'] = (df['Sex'] == 'female').astype(int)
    return df

def mask2(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['Sex_new'] = (df['Sex'].values == 'female').astype(int)
    return df


def make_df(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Sex': np.random.choice(['male','female'], size=n)})

    return df
```

---

```
perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[ma,  rep1, nwhere, mask1, mask2],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 18)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,  # rows may appear in different order
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

[image: pic]

Conclusion:

If replace only 2 values is slowiest `replace`, `numpy.where, map and mask` are similar. For improve performance compare by numpy array with `.values`.
Also all depends of data, so best test with real data.

Answer (score 2):

My instinct would have suggested to use `.map()`, but I made a comparison between your solution and map, based on a dataframe with 1500 random male/female values.

```
%timeit df_base['Sex_new'] = df_base['Sex'].map({'male': 0,'female': 1})
1000 loops, best of 3: 653 µs per loop
```

Edited Based on coldspeeds comment, and because reassigning it is a better comparison with the others:

```
%timeit df_base['Sex_new'] = df_base['Sex'].replace(['male','female'],[0,1])
1000 loops, best of 3: 968 µs per loop
```

So actually slower `.map()`...!

<s>So based on this example, your 'shoddy' solution seems faster than `.map()`...</s>

**Edit**

pygo's solution:

```
%timeit df_base['Sex_new'] = np.where(df_base['Sex'] == 'male', 0, 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 331 µs per loop
```

So faster!

Jezrael's solution with `.astype(int)`:

```
%timeit df_base['Sex_new'] = (df_base['Sex'] == 'female').astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 388 µs per loop
```

So also faster than `.map()` and `.replace()`.

Comment: What about `df['Old_Sex'] = np.where(df['Sex'] == 'male', 0, 1)` comparison?

Comment: And check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259580/replace-values-in-a-pandas-series-via-dictionary-efficiently) for `map/replace` comparison

Comment: Yes, Solution with numpy will be faster.

Comment: Or `df_base['Sex'] = (df_base['Sex'].values == 'female').astype(int)`

Comment: Note that `df_base['Sex'].replace(['male','female'],[0,1],inplace=True)` will not work because `inplace=True` on Series with replace has a history of being problematic. Assign it back.

Comment: Thank you for timings, but I get something else, `replace` is slowier for me, check my answer. What is your code for testing performance?

Comment: @jezrael: It is for me as well if I reassign it. See the edit (I posted this already at the bottom, but made it more prominent now). I really like your plot of the different options!

Comment: @NielsHenkens - Yes, I like it too, I learn it from unutbu :)

Comment: I popularised `perfplot` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028200/4909087) answer I wrote recently

Comment: @jezrael those perf plots are very nice , i'll try ti learn it :-)

Comment: @coldspeed,  the post is really nice , However what method you are using to plot the graphs perfplot?

Comment: @pygo yes, scroll to the bottom of the post, I've added all code snippets there.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you can use with `np.where`:

**Just an example DataFrame:**

```
>>> df
      Sex
0    male
1  female
2  female
3  female
4    male
```

**Based on the condition create new column `new_Sex`**

```
>>> df['new_Sex'] = np.where(df['Sex'] == 'male', 0, 1)
>>> df
      Sex  new_Sex
0    male        0
1  female        1
2  female        1
3  female        1
4    male        0
```

**OR:**

```
>>> df['new_Sex'] = np.where(df['Sex'] != 'male', 1, 0)
>>> df
      Sex  new_Sex
0    male        0
1  female        1
2  female        1
3  female        1
4    male        0
```