# Lookup in dictonary based on wildcard in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't really find any good solution to this from stackoverflow. I managed to get full word match based on iterating over the list, and assigning the value to a new column.
I guess df.lookup could also be used in some way to achieve the same, as well as df.get_value and probably also a join...

This is the solution I got working first. This is for looking up full words, but what is the best way to lookup based on wildcard and take the first result? An example could be having a list of bank transactions, trying to match against names of stores to assign a category.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("transactions.csv")

d = {
    'SUBWAY': '9',
    'TRANSFER TO': '5',
    'Best Buy': '8'
}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['Description'] in d.keys()):
        df.at[index, 'Category'] = d[row['Description']]
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: besides it being poor practice to override a builtin, naming a dictionary `list` is just confusing

Comment: I know Josh, fixed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Partial match

For partial matches of dictionary keys *within* `df['Description']`, you can iterate your dictionary *instead* of your dataframe:

```
d = {'IKEA': '9', 'TRANSFER TO SAVINGS': '5', 'Best buy': '8'}
for k, v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains(k), 'Category'] = v
```

Assuming you have a large number of rows relative to dictionary keys, this will be considerably more efficient than iterating rows.

Be careful with dictionary ordering. Pre v3.7, dictionaries should not be assumed to be ordered. In CPython v3.6 and v3.7+, dictionaries are insertion ordered. The above logic will ensure the *last* match sticks.

#### Exact match

For exact matches, you can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) followed by [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
d = {'IKEA': '9', 'TRANSFER TO SAVINGS': '5', 'Best buy': '8'}
df['Category'] = df['Description'].map(d).fillna(df['Category'])
```

The `fillna` is important as you don't want to overwrite existing values in `'Category'` with `NaN` for instances where `'Description'` is not in `d`.

A usually [less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259581/9209546) alternative which avoids `fillna` is possible via [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html).