# Look Up in Python DataFrames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1:

```
Month

1
3
March
April
2
4
5
```

I have another dataframe df2:

```
Month  Name

1       January
2       February
3       March
4       April
5       May
```

If I want to replace the integer values of df1 with the corresponding name from df2, what kind of lookup function can I use?

I want to end up with this as my df1:

```
    Month

January
March
March
April
February
May
```

Comment: why not simply use `df1['Month'] = df2['Name']` if they are ordered as shown in example?

Comment: They are not in the same order. Just made the edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html). Just be careful to map either strings to strings or, as here, numeric to numeric:

```
month_name = df2.set_index('Month')['Name']

df1['Month'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['Month'], errors='coerce').map(month_name)\
                 .fillna(df1['Month'])

print(df1)

      Month
0   January
1     March
2     March
3     April
4  February
5     April
6       May
```

You can also use [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), but this is [often inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259581/9209546).

Answer (score 5):

`replace` it

```
df1.replace(dict(zip(df2.Month.astype(str),df2.Name)))
Out[76]: 
      Month
0   January
1     March
2     March
3     April
4  February
5     April
6       May
```

Comment: I've tried it (
df1=df1.replace(dict(zip(df2.Month.astype(str),df2.Name)))) but it isn't working. When I print df1, I get the orignal values.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with a function:

```
def repl(x, lookup=dict(zip(df2.Month.astype(str), df2.Name))):
    return lookup.get(x, x)

df['Month'] = df['Month'].map(repl)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      Month
0   January
1  February
2     March
3     April
4       May
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` with a series, just need to make sure your dtypes match:

```
mapper = df2.set_index(df2['Month'].astype(str))['Name']
df1['Month'].map(mapper).fillna(df1['Month'])
```

Output:

```
0     January
1       March
2       March
3       April
4    February
5       April
6         May
Name: Month, dtype: object
```