# How to fill column values from dataframe column names based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, pandasql

I have a dataframe which contains these columns - `maxlevel, level1id, level2id, level3id`.

I need to populate a new column - `newcol_value` based on the value from `maxlevel` column.

If `maxlevel` = 1, populate the `newcol_value` with `level1id`

If `maxlevel` = 2, populate the `newcol_value` with `level2id`

If `maxlevel` = 3, populate the `newcol_value` with `level3id`

I tried this.

```
id_dict = {1:'level1id', 2:'Level2ID', 3:'level3id', 4:'level4id', 5:'level5id'}
df['id'] = df[id_dict[df['maxlevel']]]
```

But as the `df['maxlevel]` is giving series, I'm getting the following error.

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

How can I fill the `newcol_value` values based on the value in `maxlevel` column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace values in a pandas series via dictionary efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259580/replace-values-in-a-pandas-series-via-dictionary-efficiently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should using `lookup`

```
d={'level1id':1, 'Level2ID':2, 'level3id':3, 'level4id':4, 'level5id':5}


df=df.rename(columns=d)
df['New']=df.lookup(df.index,df.maxlevel)
```

Comment: No. What it did instead was just updated with `column_name`. Not with the column value. **Expected:** value in `level1id` for that row. **Actual:** `level1id`

Comment: @SukumarRdjf try replace then

Comment: No. it's still giving the same output.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf ah using the lookup , sorry overlook the question